# How can I get Mathematica to write Log instead of ArcTan?

Tags: expression-manipulation, trigonometry

`ArcTan` really bothers me, so is there a way to make *Mathematica* write `Logarithm` instead of `ArcTan`? What I'm after is some kind of a `ArcTan` to `Log` converter such as the following list from [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms)

Comment: Try `TrigToExp`, e.g. `TrigToExp @ ArcTan[x]` works as you seem to expect

Comment: That's awesome, thanks a lot man. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: So now I'm curious. What's bothering you in ArcTans?

Comment: @Vries They are way too restricted for me, $\log$s are much more general and easier to work with imho.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function you need is `TrigToExp`, e.g.

```
TrigToExp @ ArcTan[x]
```

> ```
>  1/2 I Log[1 - I x] - 1/2 I Log[1 + I x]
> ```

There is an inverse function for `TrigToExp`, namely `ExpToTrig`

```
ExpToTrig[ 1/2 I Log[1 - I x] - 1/2 I Log[1 + I x]]
```

> ```
> ArcTan[x]
> ```

They both are `Listable`:

```
Attributes @ {ExpToTrig, TrigToExp}
```

> ```
> {{Listable, Protected}, {Listable, Protected}}
> ```

Therefore you can use it e.g. this way:

```
TrigToExp [Sin[x] < x < Tan[x] ]
```

> ```
>  1/2 I E^(-I x) - 1/2 I E^(I x) < x < (I (E^(-I x) - E^(I x)))/(E^(-I x) + E^(I x))
> ```